# Subsonic and Advantage Database Server

Tags: subsonic, advantage-database-server

Does Subsonic work with Advantage Database server and if so are there any TT files to generate the necessary code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases):

Subsonic 2.2 Currently supports 5 main database engines:

- SQL Server (2000 through 2008)
- MySQL (5.0+) with special support for InnoDB
- Oracle - although we've had reports of some issues with Foreign Keys and Stored Procedures
- SQL CE (Compact Edition)
- SQLite

SubSonic 3.0 supports and has templates for:

- SQL Server (2000-2008)
- MySQL (5.0 +)
- SQLite
- Oracle support is currently in development - you can get the latest version of the templates from github. Please post details of any issues or questions to the SubSonic google group.

So in short unfortunately the answer is no.

Comment: Do you know if there is any plan to support it?

Comment: There's no plan at the moment, you're the first person to have mentioned it.